# after create new application annotations does not work

Tags: annotations, playframework-2.0

I new in Play and Scala/Java.

I install typesafe-stack from typesafe.com and create new project for test: g8 typesafehub/play-scala
After I create Java annotation TestAnn.java:

```
package ann;

import play.mvc.With;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@With(TestAnnAction.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface TestAnn {

}
```

and TestAnnAction.java`enter code here`:

```
package ann;

import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Action;

public class TestAnnAction extends Action<TestAnn> {
    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable
    {       
        System.out.println("called");

        return null;
    }
}
```

And add this to Application.scala controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

import ann.TestAnn

object Application extends Controller {

   @TestAnn
   def index = Action {
     Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
   }

}
```

Then i run application by "sbt run", but I do not saw string "called" in terminal after request index page. No errors and no results.

What I do wrong?

Update: if I create java controller all works fine.
Application.java
    package controllers;

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import ann.TestAnn;

public class Application extends Controller {

  @TestAnn
  public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call delegate.call(ctx) instead of just returning null.

```
public class TestAnnAction extends Action<TestAnn> {
    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable
    {       
        System.out.println("called");
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```